# Compound JS - Using POST method in API

Tags: node.js

I am working on CompoundJS and i would like to create an api for my mobile application.

Below is the expected output

1) An api localhost:3000/test

2) Some data has tobe POSTED to this api say `number: 1`

3) The API should respond with the number posted, result should be = `1`

I tried the below

1) Created a controller say `test_controller.js`

2) Added an action `showtest` with below code

```
action(function showtest(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

3) Added router config like

```
map.post('test', 'test#showtest')
```

When i posted to the url localhost:3000/test, it shows
like 200 successful, but in Firebug console the response shows error.

What am i doing wrong? is there anything as like Rails `render :text => "hello"` 
we can use it for CompoundJS.

Answer (score 0):

Your action isn't correct. Try this:

```
action('showtest', function() {
  for (var key in req.body)
  {
    send(key.toString());
    break;
  }
});
```

Express used to expose a `.rawBody` property on the request object, which would contain the raw data posted, but as of Express 3.x this functionality has been removed. The `for` loop in the above code will return the first key of the `req.body` object (which, when the data POST'ed is just a single number, will be that number).

Comment: Yes, this format works.. but returns `Incorrect authenticity token`, `Bad Request` message when accessing the API from mobile device.

Comment: I edited the code in case the only data posted to `/test` is just a single number.